# ¿Como hacer una correspondencia entre dos arreglos?

Tags: php, array

Tengo un arreglo como el siguiente con varios arreglos en su interior.

```
      //Arreglo original
  $arrDatosSI = array(
    array("7.261","7.215","7.218","7.305","7.499","7.499","8.21","8.67","9.17","9.7","10.28","10.91","11.57","12.28","13.09","13.96","14.87","15.73","16.57","17.38"),
    array("21.32","21.18","21.07","20.54","20.61","20.92","20.16","20.26","20.39","20.49","20.05","20.29","20.7","20.82","20.27","20.47","20.89","20.91","21.04","21.1"),
    array("25.47","27.68","26.18","27.44","25.63","26.31","27.69","26.4","25.64","26.6","24.95","26.47","25.59","24.71","26.27","26.03","26.71","27.24","27.54","28.17"),
    array("15.98","14.7","15.01","14.28","16.87","14.98","13.02","13.96","15.67","14.73","15.45","14.34","14.78","16.68","15.01","14.31","16.76","13.87","16.95","14.38")
  );
```

A los elementos de estos arreglos se les debe sacar el promedio. Para calcular el promedio divido estos arreglos por partes, para ello utilizo la función array_chunk(), entonces si dividiera los arreglos en sub arreglos de 4 elementos obtengo lo siguiente.

```
    array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "7.261"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "7.215"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "7.218"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "7.305"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "7.499"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "7.499"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "8.21"
      [3]=>
      string(4) "8.67"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "9.17"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "9.7"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "10.28"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "10.91"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "11.57"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "12.28"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "13.09"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "13.96"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "14.87"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "15.73"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "16.57"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "17.38"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "21.32"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "21.18"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "21.07"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "20.54"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "20.61"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "20.92"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "20.16"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "20.26"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "20.39"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "20.49"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "20.05"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "20.29"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "20.7"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "20.82"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "20.27"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "20.47"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "20.89"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "20.91"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "21.04"
      [3]=>
      string(4) "21.1"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "25.47"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "27.68"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "26.18"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "27.44"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "25.63"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "26.31"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "27.69"
      [3]=>
      string(4) "26.4"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "25.64"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "26.6"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "24.95"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "26.47"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "25.59"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "24.71"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "26.27"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "26.03"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "26.71"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "27.24"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "27.54"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "28.17"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "15.98"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "14.7"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "15.01"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "14.28"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "16.87"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "14.98"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "13.02"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "13.96"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "15.67"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "14.73"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "15.45"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "14.34"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "14.78"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "16.68"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "15.01"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "14.31"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "16.76"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "13.87"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "16.95"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "14.38"
    }
  }
}
```

Una vez que están divididos los arreglos calculo su promedio y los resultados los coloco en otro arreglo como el siguiente.

```
        array(20) {
  [0]=>
  float(7.25)
  [1]=>
  float(7.97)
  [2]=>
  float(10.02)
  [3]=>
  float(12.73)
  [4]=>
  float(16.14)
  [5]=>
  float(21.03)
  [6]=>
  float(20.49)
  [7]=>
  float(20.31)
  [8]=>
  float(20.57)
  [9]=>
  float(20.99)
  [10]=>
  float(26.69)
  [11]=>
  float(26.51)
  [12]=>
  float(25.92)
  [13]=>
  float(25.65)
  [14]=>
  float(27.42)
  [15]=>
  float(14.99)
  [16]=>
  float(14.71)
  [17]=>
  float(15.05)
  [18]=>
  float(15.2)
  [19]=>
  float(15.49)
}
```

Entonces lo que quiero ahora es hacer una "correspondencia" entre los arreglos originales de donde se calcularon los promedios y el arreglo de promedios que obtengo. Algo parecido a lo siguiente:

Para los primeros 4 subarreglos:

```
[0]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "7.261"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "7.215"
        [2]=>
        string(5) "7.218"
        [3]=>
        string(5) "7.305"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "7.499"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "7.499"
        [2]=>
        string(4) "8.21"
        [3]=>
        string(4) "8.67"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "9.17"
        [1]=>
        string(3) "9.7"
        [2]=>
        string(5) "10.28"
        [3]=>
        string(5) "10.91"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "11.57"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "12.28"
        [2]=>
        string(5) "13.09"
        [3]=>
        string(5) "13.96"
      }
```

Sus promedios correspondientes serian los siguientes

```
[0]=>
  float(7.25)
  [1]=>
  float(7.97)
  [2]=>
  float(10.02)
  [3]=>
  float(12.73)
```

y quisiera que los resultados estuvieran agrupados de la misma manera en que estaban agrupados los valores originales.

Este es mi código.

```
  <php

//Arreglo original
$arrDatosSI = array(
  array("7.261","7.215","7.218","7.305","7.499","7.499","8.21","8.67","9.17","9.7","10.28","10.91","11.57","12.28","13.09","13.96","14.87","15.73","16.57","17.38"),
  array("21.32","21.18","21.07","20.54","20.61","20.92","20.16","20.26","20.39","20.49","20.05","20.29","20.7","20.82","20.27","20.47","20.89","20.91","21.04","21.1"),
  array("25.47","27.68","26.18","27.44","25.63","26.31","27.69","26.4","25.64","26.6","24.95","26.47","25.59","24.71","26.27","26.03","26.71","27.24","27.54","28.17"),
  array("15.98","14.7","15.01","14.28","16.87","14.98","13.02","13.96","15.67","14.73","15.45","14.34","14.78","16.68","15.01","14.31","16.76","13.87","16.95","14.38")
);

//Intervalos de division
$intervalo = 45;
$interMuestreo = 15;

$tamFragmento = $intervalo / $interMuestreo; //Este es el numero por el que será dividido el arreglo original (En este caso es 3)

//Dividir un array en fragmentos
$newArrDatos = array();
foreach($arrDatosSI as $key => $value){
  array_push($newArrDatos, array_chunk($value, $tamFragmento)); //Division del arreglo original en arreglos por el numero $tamFragmento(3)
}

//Sacar promedio en array dentro de array
$arrProm = array();
$suma = 0;

foreach($newArrDatos as $key => $value){
  foreach($value as $k => $v){
    $suma = array_sum($v);      
    $prom = $suma/count($v);
    array_push($arrProm, round($prom, 2));
  }
}

var_dump($arrProm); //Arreglo con los promedios calculados

//Intento por dividir el arreglo de promedios para lograr la correspondencia
$arrFinal = array();
$arrProm = array_chunk($arrProm, $tamFragmento);
var_dump($arrProm);

?>
```

Espero que se entienda lo que necesito y puedan ayudarme a solucionar esto, gracias.

**Editada**

Este es un diagrama de lo que me gustaría obtener, dividir el arreglo de promedios de una manera similar a como estaban los arreglos de los valores originales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se entiende, pon un ejemplo simple de lo que esperas obtener a ver si así queda más claro. Tampoco se entiende el procedimiento que usaste para sacar los promedios ni por qué usaste ese procedimiento. Parece que partes de una solución complicada para eso del promedio y ahora quieres ayuda en medio de ese lío, quizá sea bueno que expliques en general lo que quieres hacer, desde cero, a ver si hay mejores vías de resolverlo. Lo que dices de los promedios y demás es tan confuso que creo que ya ahí empezaste mal a resolver el problema y por eso se ha agrandado.

Comment: Entiendo ya he editado mi pregunta espero que esta vez si se entienda mi problema y lo que busco.

Comment: Ahora se entiende un poco mejor, aunque no explicas a qué se debe que hayas hecho grupos de 4 valores, ¿ese es un requerimiento? Tampoco explicas cómo quieres el resultado final, ¿dónde tendría que ir el promedio (pon un ejemplo)? Lo de los grupos de 4 confunde, pon un ejemplo simple de la estructura final que necesitas, ya que no queda claro si al final quieres el arreglo sub-dividido en grupos de 4 con su promedio al lado de cada grupo...

Comment: Efectivamente @A.Cedano, los grupos de 4 es un requerimiento, sin embargo el tamaño de estos grupos es variable, pues este es calculado ya que este número corresponde a un intervalo de tiempo en el cual deben mostrarse los datos de los arreglos originales, por ello es estos se dividen en diferentes tamaños.

Comment: Bien bien, según dices, dada una variable `X` se decidirá según ella grupos de cuántos hay que hacer. ¿Estoy en lo cierto? Si es así, ¿qué pasa si el array no da para hacer grupos de `X` elementos, o sea, supongamos que da para 10 grupos de `4`, pero al final queda un elemento suelto? Tampoco indicas cómo debe quedar organizado el array final, incluyendo los promedios. Debes explicar las cosas con claridad si quieres que te ayudemos.

Comment: Así es, tal como lo dices es como se haran los grupos de valores, en caso de que un grupo no quede completo, se hará el promedio especifico para ese grupo, es decir si de 10 datos hay dos grupos de 4 y al final queda uno de 2 el promedio se calculará para esos 2 datos. Una disculpa, por no dar tanta información trate de ser lo más breve y claro posible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que esto te puede servir. Lo que se hace es calcular el promedio de cada grupo y agregarlo a ese grupo bajo la clave `avg`.

Está todo comentado en el código. También puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMO EN REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/UAYQ75093)**</kbd>, y hacer pruebas sobre el código.

```
$arrFinal=array();
$subLimit=4;
foreach ($arrDatosSI as $subArray){
    /*Creamos subgrupos de $subLimit*/
    $newGroup=array_chunk($subArray,$subLimit);

    /*Calculamos el promedio y lo agregamos al grupo bajo la clave avg*/
    foreach($newGroup as $k=>$chunk) {
      (float) $avg= round(array_sum($chunk) / count($chunk),2);
       $newGroup[$k]['avg']=$avg;
    }
    /*Agregamos el grupo al array final*/
    $arrFinal[]=$newGroup;
}
/*Prueba*/
print_r($arrFinal);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 7.261
                    [1] => 7.215
                    [2] => 7.218
                    [3] => 7.305
                    [avg] => 7.25
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 7.499
                    [1] => 7.499
                    [2] => 8.21
                    [3] => 8.67
                    [avg] => 7.97
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9.17
                    [1] => 9.7
                    [2] => 10.28
                    [3] => 10.91
                    [avg] => 10.02
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11.57
                    [1] => 12.28
                    [2] => 13.09
                    [3] => 13.96
                    [avg] => 12.73
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14.87
                    [1] => 15.73
                    [2] => 16.57
                    [3] => 17.38
                    [avg] => 16.14
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 21.32
                    [1] => 21.18
                    [2] => 21.07
                    [3] => 20.54
                    [avg] => 21.03
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20.61
                    [1] => 20.92
                    [2] => 20.16
                    [3] => 20.26
                    [avg] => 20.49
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20.39
                    [1] => 20.49
                    [2] => 20.05
                    [3] => 20.29
                    [avg] => 20.31
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20.7
                    [1] => 20.82
                    [2] => 20.27
                    [3] => 20.47
                    [avg] => 20.57
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20.89
                    [1] => 20.91
                    [2] => 21.04
                    [3] => 21.1
                    [avg] => 20.99
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 25.47
                    [1] => 27.68
                    [2] => 26.18
                    [3] => 27.44
                    [avg] => 26.69
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 25.63
                    [1] => 26.31
                    [2] => 27.69
                    [3] => 26.4
                    [avg] => 26.51
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 25.64
                    [1] => 26.6
                    [2] => 24.95
                    [3] => 26.47
                    [avg] => 25.92
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 25.59
                    [1] => 24.71
                    [2] => 26.27
                    [3] => 26.03
                    [avg] => 25.65
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 26.71
                    [1] => 27.24
                    [2] => 27.54
                    [3] => 28.17
                    [avg] => 27.42
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 15.98
                    [1] => 14.7
                    [2] => 15.01
                    [3] => 14.28
                    [avg] => 14.99
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16.87
                    [1] => 14.98
                    [2] => 13.02
                    [3] => 13.96
                    [avg] => 14.71
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 15.67
                    [1] => 14.73
                    [2] => 15.45
                    [3] => 14.34
                    [avg] => 15.05
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14.78
                    [1] => 16.68
                    [2] => 15.01
                    [3] => 14.31
                    [avg] => 15.2
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16.76
                    [1] => 13.87
                    [2] => 16.95
                    [3] => 14.38
                    [avg] => 15.49
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia @A.Cedano lo probare, intentare dejar ahora solo los elementos con clave "avg", pues la estructura que tienen me sirve pero los demás datos no. Comentare los resultados obtenidos.

Comment: Si lo que te interesa es un Array aparte con los promedios puedes crear un Array al principio, por ejemplo: `$arrAvg=array();` y dentro del bucle, en vez de esto: `$newGroup[$k]['avg']=$avg;` pones esto: **`$arrAvg[]=$avg;`**

Comment: Entendido ya mismo lo pruebo.

Comment: @A.Cenado Ya lo he probado, pero lo que obtengo es un arreglo con 4 arreglos internos en donde el primer arreglo tiene los 5 primeros promedios, en el siguiente, aparecen los mismos promedios mas los 5 promedios siguientes y así sucesivamente. La idea es conservar la estructura como están los promedios, pero sin los valores originales

Comment: @Robert_Rmz debe ser que lo estás haciendo mal. Es este bloque el que debes modificar así: `/*Calculamos el promedio...*/ foreach($newGroup as $k=>$chunk) { (float) $avg= round(array_sum($chunk) / count($chunk),2); $arrAvg[]=$avg; }` ...

Comment: Lo he probado con `print_r($arrAvg);` y me da un array con todos los promedios: `Array
(
    [0] => 7.25
    [1] => 7.97
    [2] => 10.02
    [3] => 12.73
    [4] => 16.14
    [5] => 21.03
    [6] => 20.49
    [7] => 20.31
    [8] => 20.57
    [9] => 20.99
    [10] => 26.69
    [11] => 26.51
    [12] => 25.92
    [13] => 25.65
    [14] => 27.42
    [15] => 14.99
    [16] => 14.71
    [17] => 15.05
    [18] => 15.2
    [19] => 15.49
)`

Comment: En efecto @A. Cedano Me sale de la misma manera, es un array con 20 elementos, a lo que me refería yo era que quería conservar el array con la estructura que resulta al agregar la clave 'avg' al mismo grupo del array donde están lo valores originales, pero sin estos, solo conservando el 'avg'

Comment: Lo siento pero no logro entender qué es lo que quieres ¿? @Robert_Rmz

Comment: Quiero lograr tener esta estructura @A. Cedano     [0] => Array(
      [0] => Array([avg] => 7.25)
      [1] => Array([avg] => 7.97)
      [2] => Array([avg] => 10.02)
      [3] => Array([avg] => 12.73)
      [4] => Array([avg] => 16.14)
      )

Comment: Si se da cuenta he eliminado el resto de los elementos del array y solo he dejado los elementos con 'avg', esto conserva la estructura del array que necesito

Comment: @Robert_Rmz ¿Es algo como esto lo que quieres: En el bucle que crea el promedio: `$arrAvg[$k]['avg']=$avg;` y luego agregas al array final: `$arrFinal[]=$arrAvg;` la salida de `print_r($arrFinal);` sería algo así: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 7.25
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 7.97
                )...`

Comment: Así es @A. Cedano eso es lo que necesito

Comment: Pues ya lo tienes, ¿no? Primero esto: `$arrAvg[$k]['avg']=$avg;` y luego agregas al array final: `$arrFinal[]=$arrAvg;` y tendrás el resultado deseado en la variable **`$arrFinal`**

Comment: Perfecto, quedo bien le agradezco @A. Cedano , marco su respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le sirve esto en un futuro y en base a la respuesta y sugerencias del compañero A. Cedano, el código queda de la siguiente manera.

```
    <?php

  //Arreglo original
  $arrDatosSI = array(
    array("7.261","7.215","7.218","7.305","7.499","7.499","8.21","8.67","9.17","9.7","10.28","10.91","11.57","12.28","13.09","13.96","14.87","15.73","16.57","17.38"),
    array("21.32","21.18","21.07","20.54","20.61","20.92","20.16","20.26","20.39","20.49","20.05","20.29","20.7","20.82","20.27","20.47","20.89","20.91","21.04","21.1"),
    array("25.47","27.68","26.18","27.44","25.63","26.31","27.69","26.4","25.64","26.6","24.95","26.47","25.59","24.71","26.27","26.03","26.71","27.24","27.54","28.17"),
    array("15.98","14.7","15.01","14.28","16.87","14.98","13.02","13.96","15.67","14.73","15.45","14.34","14.78","16.68","15.01","14.31","16.76","13.87","16.95","14.38")
  );

  $arrFinal = array(); //Arreglo donde se colocaran los promedios calculados
  $subLimit = 4; //Numero de sub arreglos en los que se fragmentaran los arreglos internos de $arrDatosSI

  //Recorrido para crear los sub arreglos
  foreach ($arrDatosSI as $subArray){
      /*Creamos subgrupos de $subLimit*/
      $newGroup=array_chunk($subArray,$subLimit);

      /*Calculamos el promedio y lo agregamos al grupo bajo la clave avg*/
      foreach($newGroup as $k=>$chunk) {
        (float) $avg= round(array_sum($chunk) / count($chunk),2);                  
          $arrAvg[$k]['avg'] = $avg;        
      }
      /*Se agrega el promedio calculado al array final con la clave 'avg'*/
      $arrFinal[] = $arrAvg;
  }

  //Impresion del arreglo final
  print_r($arrFinal);
?>
```

**Arreglo obtenido.**

```
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 7.25
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 7.97
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 10.02
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 12.73
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 16.14
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 21.03
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 20.49
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 20.31
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 20.57
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 20.99
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 26.69
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 26.51
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 25.92
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 25.65
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 27.42
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 14.99
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 14.71
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 15.05
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 15.2
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [avg] => 15.49
                )

        )

)
```